Very Slow ICE candidates gathering on webrtc
I am using cloudflare TURN servers. I saw a weird behaviour that if I reset website's permission, the ICE candidates gathering is pretty fast and without it, it can take upto 40 seconds.
I've tried, using no-cache, hosting my own TURN server (cotrun) but nothing worked.
I am using this example https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/tree/main/examples/server from AIORTC python.
You can try: https://simplici-webrtc.satschel.com/ the hosted version. Please check the "use STUN server" option. You can check the frontend js code on the website itself.
Thankyou!
I've tried, using no-cache, hosting my own TURN server (cotrun) but nothing worked.
